# Welcome travelers and locals to your premises

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, north-american-english, dialects

"Welcome travelers and locals to your premises."

I believe that sentence would be understood by Australian/NZ people. I'm just checking, is that something an American would understand and use?

It's the subject line in a letter to businesses offering them for example our new welcome signs and mats.

Comment: In the U.S., we would certainly understand it. But I don't think it's anything we'd use.

Comment: @PeterShor "local customers" then?

Comment: It's more the word *premises* that's the problem. That's a word you would find in legal writing and in formal writing, but it's not an everyday word here.

Comment: What do you think that phrase means? Is it an instruction? Is it what you say to those visiting your shop? How can we say whether it would be understood without knowing **how** it should be understood?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Oh yes apologies. I see what you mean. It's a letter to businesses offering them for example our new welcome signs and mats.

Comment: @user1946932 Please [edit] your question to include all relevant data. Don't bury it in comments. (You may already be doing that; in which case, thank you.)

Comment: Is it meant to be a request/instruction to businesses that they should welcome people; is it meant to be an actual act of welcoming to the named people; or are you are describing a category of welcomes?

Comment: @StuartF Basically get our nice welcome mats so you can welcome customers.

Comment: "Welcome travelers and locals to your establishment" (or "business").

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it will be understood as you would like it to be.

With "your" it reads like an imperative addressed to business owners.

Replace "your" with "our" and it's a rather awkward greeting. More natural would be "... to our hotel" (or shop, restaurant, etc.)

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding. It is actually for business owners.